# mod_fcgi with huge number of errors

Tags: apache2, centos, fastcgi, plesk

I have found that `/var/log/sw-cp-server/error_log` contains huge amount of following errors:

```
("huge" means 569000+ "errors" in last week):
(mod_fastcgi.c.3805) pid  17427 5 not found: No child processes
```

This server freezes sometimes and this is the only "error" I am able to find anywhere in the logs. I am not able, however, to locate and fix this problem.

Comment: What software are you using behind your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found today that parallels offer a solution for this issue since May 2012:

http://kb.parallels.com/en/113418